# Why do I get this : [LMyStack.Node@addbf1 when I try to print right values of Stack?

Tags: java, stack

Here is my Java code to create a Stack and pop one Node from Stack. But when I added Nodes to `Node[]`, the values I get when I print to the screen are : **[LMyStack.Node;@addbf1**.

I don't know what is problem. Any help?

```
 public class MyStack{
    private Node[] values;
    public MyStack(){

    }
    public MyStack(Node[] values){
        this.values=values;
    }
    //pop one Node from Stack
    public Node pop(){
        Node result=null;
        if(values!=null && values.length-1>0){
            result = values[values.length-1];
            Node[] temp = new Node[values.length-1];
            for(int i=0;i<values.length-1;i++){
                temp[i]=values[i];
            }
            this.values=temp;
            //Print the stack to screen
            System.out.println("The stack is:"+this.value); 
        }

        return result;

    }
}
class Node {
    private int value;
    public Node(){
        value=0;
    }
    public Node(int value){
        this.value=value;
    }
}
class Result{
    public static void main(String []args){
        Node node1 = new Node(1);
        Node node2 = new Node(2);
        Node node3 = new Node(3);
        //Here is problem
        Node[] n = {node1, node2, node3};
        //System.out.println("Node is: "+n[1] );
        MyStack stack = new MyStack(n);
        stack.pop();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many examples of this on Stack Overflow.  Please remember to search first!

What you're seeing is the default `toString()` method called on an array of Node objects.  `[LMyStack.Node` indicates array of Node instances and `addbf1` is the hexadecimal representation of the hashcode.  Use a loop:

```
for (Node node : values) {
    System.out.println(node);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, i'll search the same questions before ask any question!

Comment: Choose answer if it helps you?

Comment: I think the loop you use here is foreach(Node in values) ?

Comment: Oh, no, it's my mistake, this is foreach in Java. Thank you, it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

System.out.println("The stack is:"+this.value); by default will be considered as  System.out.println("The stack is:"+this.value.toString()); at run-time which returns classname@hashcode

default  `toString()` implementation in `Object` calls it..

```
 public String toString() {
    return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but when i add this.value.toString(), i'm still get the same problem. Any idea?

Comment: That's what he's trying to tell you, this is the expected result... Look at my answer for more explanation of what you should do.